# Что такое метаданные в java?

Tags: java

Столкнулся с таким предложением: "WeakReference отлично подходит для хранения метаданных, например, для хранения ссылки на ClassLoader".
Однако найти чёткого определения термина "метаданные" мне так и не удалось

Answer (score 3):

Метаданные это данные о данных. Дополнительная информация, которая может сопровождать классы, интерфейсы, методы.

Аннотации, как пример, являются формой метаданных.

Здесь приведены примеры: https://www.javatpoint.com/what-is-meta-data